# Make file problems when compiling TBB with MinGW for Windows

Tags: tbb, mingw-w64

As the title says, I am attempting to compile TBB (2018_1 Version) with MingW (5.3.0) for windows. I generate and execute tbbvars.bat for the environment variables and then call make. Which yields the following errors:

```
MAKE Version 5.2  Copyright (c) 1987, 1998 Inprise Corp.
Error makefile 21: Command syntax error
Error makefile 26: Colon expected
```

But I have not moified the included make file, which looks like this:

```
tbb_root?=.
include $(tbb_root)/build/common.inc
.PHONY: default all tbb tbbmalloc tbbproxy test examples ##line 21

#workaround for non-depend targets tbb and tbbmalloc which both depend on version_string.ver
#According to documentation, recursively invoked make commands can  process their targets in parallel
.NOTPARALLEL: tbb tbbmalloc tbbproxy

default: tbb tbbmalloc $(if $(use_proxy),tbbproxy)  ##line 27
```

Comment: AFAIK, TBB does not work well with cygwin/mingw environments. the reason is incompatibility between cmd and sh. try to rename sh.exe for sake of experiments, it might fix the issue with the TBB makefile

Answer (score 0):

For building TBB from sources try next guidance:

1. Open mingw command line (or source environment from mingw's bat file)
2. change directory to `unpacked_tbb/src`
3. execute `make tbb tbbmalloc stdver=c++11 compiler=gcc`

You should use `tbbvars.bat` only for development purposes(e.g. add library to the PATH environment or add path to headers)

In case of issues please provide a full log

Comment: Thx. But this does not work either - same error. I also cannot see any log file or error messages besides those above.

Comment: Which mingw do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your make utility:

> MAKE Version 5.2  Copyright (c) 1987, 1998 Inprise Corp.

For building TBB, you should use GNU Make 3.81 or later.